# $_SESSION variable not visible in $GLOBALS

Tags: php

I am new to this and don't want to just go and change my or a colleague's php.ini.

I have Windows and he has Ubuntu set up.

I have 2 pages `login.php` and `main.php` with the following code at the top of each page

> ```
> if(session_id() == '') {
>     session_start();
> }
> ```

I set a session variable to 1 or 0 depending if the user loggin in is a admin or not.

after clicking login you are taken to main.php. At the top of the page I did a `print_r($GLOBALS)` and I can see quite a lot of the global variables including the `$_SESSION['admin']` entry.

On my colleague's pc there is only about 5 globals showing and `$_SESSION` is not there.

Is it a `php.ini` setup issue? Where do I start looking to fix this?

Comment: You have to call session_start(); in every page.

Comment: php.ini shouldn't have anything to do with this.

Comment: session.auto_start setting could make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You have to call session_start(); in every page. –  Naktibalda

Right

> php.ini shouldn't have anything to do with this. –  serakfalcon

Wrong

Then why it works on one machine and not on the other? **[session.auto_start](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start)** in `php.ini`

> **session.auto_start Boolean**
>
> session.auto_start specifies whether the session module starts a session automatically on request startup. Defaults to 0 (disabled).

To not depend on that, you need to have

```
session_start();
```

On top of every page where you want to access or manipulate session data.

Comment: So doing `if(session_id() == '') {
    session_start();
}` is not the right approach. It should just be plain `session_start();`? Am I right in saying that?

Comment: Exactly, and it needs to be above any other code that manipulates the output. Not even after a blank HTML line etc